# Rename refactoring in a XML file using XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to implement rename refactoring for an input XML file. I have an XML file which is in fact a representation of an input Java program. The XML file for a simple Java program are as below:

```
public class main {
   private String str;
   public void print() {
        str= "Hello World!";
        System.out.println(str);}
}
```

The resulted XML file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit xmlns="http://www.sdml.info/srcML/src" language="Java" filename="main.java">
<class><specifier>public</specifier> class <name>main</name> 
<block>{

<decl_stmt><decl><type><specifier>private</specifier><name>String</name></type> <name>str</name></decl>;</decl_stmt>

<function><type><specifier>public</specifier> <name>void</name></type> <name>print</name><parameter_list>()</parameter_list> <block>{
    <expr_stmt><expr><name>str</name> = "Hello World!"</expr>;</expr_stmt>
    <expr_stmt><expr><call><name><name>System</name>.<name>out</name>.<name>println</name></name><argument_list>(<argument><expr><name>str</name></expr></argument>)</argument_list></call></expr>;</expr_stmt>     
}</block></function>
}</block></class>
</unit>
```

I want to select an element and then find all its references using XPath expression. For example, in the above example, I want to select the field "str" and then returns two places where it is used. Then I can rename all of them to the new name.

Note that I can not add new detailed information to the XML file (such as adding an ID to the field and IDref to its references). The above XML file is all information that I can have for the above input Java program.

Another note is that if I define a variable with name "str" in the function "print" then both references to str are refereed to this variable and not to the field. Therefore, they are not references of the field. (-:

It is good if anyone can help me with a XPath solution as my program is based on XPath queries. However, please also let me know if there is another simple way such as an API that I can use to programmatically implement rename refactoring in the XML file.

Comment: What will be the exact parameter input to your XPath expression? The String e.g. `"str"`? What about the block structure and scoping? In principle you will have to restrict your search to the innermost block containing the declaration of the variable.

Comment: I have XPath expression for the field. I can also determine its scope. For example in the above example the scope is the entire class. Therefore, the solution can take scope and XPath expression of the filed as input (clearly when I have Xpath for the field I have its name as well).

Comment: Suppose `BlockContext` is your context point the the block and `TokenName` is a String containing the token. You could build an XPath expression to select all the relevant `<name>` nodes like this: `"descendant-or-self::name[text() = '" + TokenName + "']"` executed on `BlockContext`. Is this vaguely what you are looking for?

Comment: This solution can help, but when I define scope as class, and I have similar variable in the function (like example in the question), then it returns wrong references. It detects references to the variable as reference to the field. I think it is not easy to implement a comprehensive rename refactoring using XPath. Maybe a better solution is to use a Java API to do that. Any suggestions for an API?

Comment: So, you have to restrict the search to the axis `following::node` but EXCLUDING all nodes in the axis `following-siblings::node` of the parent. Tricky!